# Opening a SSL socket connection in Python

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to establish a secure socket connection in Python, and i'm having a hard time with the SSL bit of it.  I've found some code examples of how to establish a connection with SSL, but they all involve key files.  The server i'm trying to connect with doesn't need to receive any keys or certificates.  My question is how do I essentially wrap a python socket connection with SSL. I know for a fact that the cipher i'm suppose to use is `ADH-AES256-SHA`, and the protocol is `TLSv1`.  This is what i've been trying:

```
import socket
import ssl

# SET VARIABLES
packet, reply = "<packet>SOME_DATA</packet>", ""
HOST, PORT = 'XX.XX.XX.XX', 4434

# CREATE SOCKET
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(10)

# WRAP SOCKET ???
ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version="TLSv1", ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")

# CONNECT AND PRINT REPLY
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
sock.send(packet)
print sock.recv(1280)

# CLOSE SOCKET CONNECTION
sock.close()
```

When I run this code, I don't get any errors, but I get a blank response.  When trying to debug this code in the command line, by typing in `python` in the terminal and pasting in code line by line, I get what i'm assuming is a status code when running `sock.send(packet)`.  The integer response I get is `26`.  If anyone knows what this means, or can help in anyway it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was wrong.  It was kind of foolish of me.  I had `two` problems with my code.  My first mistake was when specifying the `ssl_version` I put in `TLSv1` when it should have been `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1`.  The second mistake was that I wasn't referencing the wrapped socket, instead I was calling the original socket that I have created.  The below code seemed to work for me.

```
import socket
import ssl

# SET VARIABLES
packet, reply = "<packet>SOME_DATA</packet>", ""
HOST, PORT = 'XX.XX.XX.XX', 4434

# CREATE SOCKET
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(10)

# WRAP SOCKET
wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")

# CONNECT AND PRINT REPLY
wrappedSocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
wrappedSocket.send(packet)
print wrappedSocket.recv(1280)

# CLOSE SOCKET CONNECTION
wrappedSocket.close()
```

Hope this can help somebody!

Comment: I got this error: `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure`

any idea?

Comment: Hard to tell from just the output.  Did you use the code snippet above?  If not, i'd open a new question up and post the code that you're using :)

Comment: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:590). Over GNU/Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @Kostanos You can try using a different cipher. I.e. replace `ADH-AES256-SHA` with `AES256-SHA`. If that doesn't work, try using `TLSv1.2` with `AES256-SHA256`. Most likely the server either doesn't support the cipher or the protocol.

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't be setting `PROTOCOL_TLSv1` (or `TLSv1`). This restricts the connection to `TLS` v1.0 only. Instead you want `PROTOCOL_TLS` (or the deprecated `PROTOCOL_SSLv23`) that supports all versions supported by the library.

You're using an anonymous cipher, because for some reason you think you don't need a certificate or key. This means that there is no authentication of the server and that you're vulnerable to a man in the middle attack. Unless you really know what you're doing, I suggest you don't use anonymous ciphers (like `ADH-AES256-SHA`).

Comment: Do you think you could provide example of how to implement a certificate or key versus just saying not to use an anonymous cipher?

Comment: As things go, now `PROTOCOL_TLS` is also deprecated, in favor of either `PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT` or `PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html for up-to-date information.

Answer (score 10):

I was looking for a good working ssl socket that starts the connection with a https package. This helped me a lot but is a little outdated, so here is the code for python3:

```py
import socket
import ssl

package = "GET /ws/LiveWebcastUpdate/22000557 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 
www.website_name.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; 
rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Language: nl,en- 
US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nOrigin: 
https://www.website_name.com\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: 
NU/EsJMICjSociJ751l0Xw==\r\nConnection: keep-alive, Upgrade\r\nPragma: no- 
cache\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\n\r\n"

hostname = 'www.website_name.com'
port = 443

context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, port)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
        ssock.send(package.encode())
        while True:
            data = ssock.recv(2048)
            if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
                break
            print(data)
```

This is as simple as possible, for more information visit
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of fun to be had solving these problems but for me, I found that the underlying infrastructure for python ssl is openssl.  Try validating your certificates with openssl and do this before you try to get python to use that same stack.

I needed to import a root certificate into openssl before I could validate the leaf certificate.

This was helpful.
http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml#ca-openssl

Another interesting thing was that two different build of the same version of python on different hosts had different methods. One had `ssl.get_default_verify_paths()` and the other didn't had any at all.  The lesson here is that python ssl is built on **openssl**.  Different underlying libraries give you a different python.

Python SSL is built on openssl so solve certificate issues in openssl first.