# Can't get python https socket to connect

Tags: python, sockets

So I have an apache web server installed on a vm. I want to write a simple script that will get the home page of the website using a socket. I was able to do it without ssl, but I recently installed ssl and thought I should try using the ssl version. This is the code I have, based off of another question [Opening a SSL socket connection in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851034/opening-a-ssl-socket-connection-in-python)

```
import socket, ssl
s = socket.socket()
wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
wrappedSocket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 443))
wrappedSocket.sendall(
    'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n'
    'Host: vulnerable\r\n'
    'User-Agent: sslsocket.py\r\n'
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n'
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n'
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n'
    'Connection: keep-alive\r\n'
    '\r\n'

)
ans = wrappedSocket.recv(4096)
print ans
```

The script keeps on running and never outputs anything. Upon further debugging, I found out it breaks on the connect() function call, but am unable to figure out why it happens.

Edit- After some help in the comments, I realised that the domain name is 127.0.1.1. However, now I get the HTTP headers as output, but it doesn't actually give me the HTML of the page. What is wrong this time?

Comment: what is the error code ?

Comment: @AlokThakur thanks for commenting! There is no error code unfortunately which is just pissing me off, all I get is a blank output and the program runs forever :( I'm really stuck, I debugged by putting each logical line of code in the terminal by typing python and then running the code and when I type `wrappedSocket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 443))` it runs forever and never outputs anything any idea?

Comment: You have verified that connecting with a browser/curl to https://127.0.0.1:443 works as expected?

To me it sounds like the TCP connection succeeds, but the SSL handshake hangs waiting for input from the server.

Comment: @HenrikGustafsson I'm checking on that, I assumed it was my code that was wrong thanks for the tip I believe it might be that.

Comment: @HenrikGustafsson you are right, I'm having issues with server configuration (namely, pid conflicts, what ever that is. I know how to fix them and am researching how to prevent them) and apparently it switched from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.1.1 as the domain name :) Now it connects, but it only gives me half the message.

Comment: Why don't just use requests?

Comment: @Ashalynd learning purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems liike you're really close, and Henrik has already addressed the issues about your connection.

If you are only recieving half of the message, it is probably due to the limit you put on recv. Try increasing that, or using the makefile method so you don't have to worry about the limit.

Edit: To show what makefile is and can do.

```
my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket_input = my_socket.makefile('r')
my_socket_output = my_socket.makefile('w')
```

These new tools make doing things much simpler, as if you were writing and reading to a file. With your new socket_input variable, you can call methods like readline, and with socket_output, you can call methods like write.

```
some_text = my_socket_input.readline()
```

One of the details you don't need to worry about your is the buffer size on recv, as the makefile handles that for you

Comment: I don't know what the makefile method is, I'll look it up and try it out.

Comment: Wait so I can just makefile the socket, then instead of using recv I used read?

Comment: Thanks that did it for me much better thanks a lot man :) This makefile method is awesome, I wish I had known about it before.

Comment: Yep, no need to use recv. Glad it helps!