# How to encrypt socket connection in python

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, encryption, tls1.2

I am trying to encrypt a python socket. I have the below code that is able to send a message from the client to the server. I am wondering how I can implement some sort of encryption to secure the connection.

I know that I could encrypt the data on the client, then send the encrypted message over the existing socket to the server to then be decrypted on the server using a secret key or passphrase, but that's not what I'm trying to do.

I know that when you visit a website that has https enabled, your unencrypted data is sent through a secure tunnel that can't be viewed by a MITM attack. I'm trying to do the same thing but with a python socket and I'm wondering how to implement this if it's at all possibe.

I'm very new to python, so any help from external resources to a full code example would be greatly appreciated

```
server:
import socket 
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = "*Server IP*"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

Client:

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = "*Server IP*"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))

user_input = None
while user_input != "exit":
    user_input = (input())
    send(user_input)


send(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening a SSL socket connection in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851034/opening-a-ssl-socket-connection-in-python)

Comment: This discussion in the [docs for the python ssl module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) really is fairly good, with several simple examples that can be used to get started.